# Title screen numbers in Japanese films

Tags: japanese-cinema

On many Japanese films from the 30s to the 50s there is a number next to or under the title as the film opens. For example Ozu’s *Brothers and Sisters of the Toda Family* (Shōchiku 1941) is A44 ; *Record of a Tenement Gentleman* (Shōchiku 1947) is I.146. Naruse’s *Three Sisters with Maiden Hearts* (PCL Tōhō 1935) is “no.10”, *Inazuma* (Daiei 1952) is 792. there are many other examples.

Films earlier than the mid 30s or later than the late 50s don’t seem to have them. There isn’t a clear correlation between the studio and the number. Their presence is not systematic, some films don’t have them when you might expect them to. The numbers are sometimes in boxes, sometimes in circles, sometimes by themselves. Sometimes they’re clearly part of the original title “page” but usually added “a posteriori” but probably before release - different prints or restorations of the same film all have the same number.

I had wondered if they might be related to CI&E (postwar occupation censors) but that doesn’t seem to be the case.

Comment: For a partial answer it’s very complete and i thank you immensely. I’d like to bother you further with a tenuously related question concerning Heinosuke Kinugasa’s 1935 *Revenge of an Actor* ( 雪之丞変化 ): there’s a popular conception that it was shredded by American censors. My limited knowledge  makes me think this can’t be the case, but I would be interested in your far more expert opinion.

Comment: BPP - Very hard to find solid information on this. Only that most do infer that GHQ/SCAP did the cut. The film, first of a trilogy, was incredibly successful on its release in Japan, which points to it unlikely being cut domestically. However, at this time there was a rise in Imperial codes and censorship which was having an effect on what could be shot and what could remain after being shot. [1of2]

Comment: BPP - The GHQ was just as harsh if not more so in its heavy handed censorship of Japanese media so it would not be far fetched for them to have cut it. By 1963 with the idea of the remake being touted, the 1935 version was already referred to as being left to rot in storage or had already been long lost by then.  [2of2]

Comment: blobbymcblobby - I think “heavy handed” is a good term for GHQ intervention - not particularly draconian but unpredictable, inconsistent, often insensitive. You bring up the idea of physical deterioration, that seems the right guess to me. As I understand it CI&E never did any editing themselves, leaving it to the studios and judging whether those cuts brought the movie into line with their 13 directives. Note that the film as we know it today is very far from compliant with those; if 2/3 of the film was cut, it’s hard to understand how what’s left could still be there.

Comment: the 1952 re-release date tends to back up the idea of the film rotting away and not being snipped to pieces while in GHQ possession: CCD stopped operation in 1949, but the archive of films that had not passed censorship weren’t released until the end of occupation.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer follows:

Look at both Inazumas card:
[image]

and at Tokyo Storys card:
[image]

The seal at the bottom right, with the certificate number is of the 管理委員会, with 映倫 in the center.

(literally: Management Committee, Eirin)

Established in 1949, The Motion Picture Code of Ethics Committee, was the forerunner of todays Eirin, which changed to its current format in 1956.

You are correct in that the post-war occupation censors was linked: Eirin's formation was modelled on the Production Code Administration, produced by the Motion Picture Producers and Distributors of America, whilst under occupation by Allied Forces.

So from 1949, films that were classified and passed by Eirin were allowed to be shown in cinemas, and showed the circular seal.

Prior to the establishment of Eirin, from 1930s onwards Japans cinema was censored by the Interior Ministry and Police Bureau (partially due to the massive influx of Hollywood films that were incredibly popular but made the Japanese authorities unhappy). So the certification was likely different as you saw in that period, with the 1939 Film Law making yet another impact on certification less than a decade later.

So between 1930s and 1949 there is likely to be a variety of seals or stamps of approval applied to the films, not least because the agencies that were doing the examining were changing both names and ministries in that time period.

With reference to PCL, this existed for a short period of time before becoming Toho in 1937, so the number might be an internal reference, as it literally means 'Works number 10' - between 1933 and 1934 roughly that number of live action features were made at PCL, for example (the rest being shorts and animations).

*To confirm PCL's output, I looked at Botchan and The Actress and the Poet, both made in 1935 and released after Three Sisters with Maiden Hearts. Botchan is Works Number 11 and The Actress and the Poet is Works Number 12, thereby confirming that the number is just the studio's internal reference to the number of live action features made, and not to do with classification or censorship*

With the American occupation all these formerly Imperial Japan movie certifications were swept aside for the formation of Eirin.

Prior to the 1930s, and the Pure Film movement (introducing film techniques to Japanese film making from overseas industries such as Hollywood), Japan had its own industry that favored the old style of story-telling (Benshi, as a side narrator for example; Benshi was also used for early foreign silent movies that were imported without translated title cards, and it was still normal to have men depicting female characters) and had very little foreign influence in it and so in these early days of Japanese cinema it is likely that censorship was not considered necessary.

Modern Eirin is referenced here:
https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2010/03/02/reference/all-movies-subject-to-rating-even-cuts/

> Moviegoers in Japan may have noticed that either during the opening or ending credits of a feature film, a mark appears on the screen bearing two kanji enclosed in a circle.

> This logo is proof that the film has been rated by Eirin, the Film Classification and Rating Committee

Not directly related, but an interesting piece regarding the state of Japans cinema in the 1930s, Hollywoods influence, and the bans introduced on films prior to World War Two.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1758-5899.12818

Link to the history of PCL:

https://tohostudiopedia.fandom.com/wiki/Photo_Chemical_Laboratories

Comment: very interesting info! Great answer!